# jQuery table column filter with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

I have an HTML table that should be filtered by a selected value from a dropdown list when the button is pressed.

I'm using jQuery selectors `#table_id td.[td class]:contains` and `#table_id td.[td class]:not(:contains)`. Everything looks fine but the `:not(:contains)` selector returns " Syntax error, unrecognized expression". It works in a same way in other examples, but can't make it work for some reason.

```js
$(function() {    
    $('#butt1').click(function() { 
        $("#tast td.col1:contains('" + $('#selector1').val() + "')").parent().show();
        $("#tast td.col1:not(:contains('" + $('#selector1').val() + "'))").parent().hide();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<select id="selector1"><option value="all">All</option><option value="
Sample 1
">
Sample 1
</option></select>
<button id="butt1">
Filter
</button>
<table id="tast" class="TableStyle0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="90">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Code</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="203">
<p><strong>Dir</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="136">
<p><strong>Inst</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Form</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="91">
<p><strong>Quota</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Target</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Total</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Total payed</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="81">
<p><strong>Told</strong></p>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="col1" valign="bottom" width="90">
<p>38.03.02</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="203">
<p>Sample 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="136">
<p>Data 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>Text 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="91">
<p>1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>4</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>5</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="81">
<p>60</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="90">
<p>38.03.02</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="203">
<p>Sample 2</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="136">
<p>Data 2</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>Text 3</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="91">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="81">
<p>25</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `.siblings()` to select all not valid elements, then invoke `.hide()` instead of `:not(:contains())` as it is more intuitive and will reduce repetitive code.

```js
$(function() {    
    $('#butt1').click(function() { 
        $("#tast td.col1:contains('" + $('#selector1').val() + "')").parent().show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<select id="selector1"><option value="all">All</option><option value="
Sample 1
">
Sample 1
</option></select>
<button id="butt1">
Filter
</button>
<table id="tast" class="TableStyle0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="90">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Code</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="203">
<p><strong>Dir</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="136">
<p><strong>Inst</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Form</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="91">
<p><strong>Quota</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Target</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Total</strong></p>
</th>
<th  style="text-align: center;" width="98">
<p><strong>Total payed</strong></p>
</th>
<th style="text-align: center;" width="81">
<p><strong>Told</strong></p>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="col1" valign="bottom" width="90">
<p>38.03.02</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="203">
<p>Sample 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="136">
<p>Data 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>Text 1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="91">
<p>1</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>4</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>5</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="81">
<p>60</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="90">
<p>38.03.02</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="203">
<p>Sample 2</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="136">
<p>Data 2</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>Text 3</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="91">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="98">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td class="col1"valign="bottom" width="81">
<p>25</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks! I added the code to show columns after hiding unnecessary ones `$(function() {    
    $('#butt1').click(function() { 
     $("#tast td.col1:contains('" + $('#selector1').val() + "')").parent().show().siblings().hide();
        $("#tast td.col1:contains('" + $('#selector1').val() + "')").parent().show();
    });
    
});`